# Can't pause screen on C++ using Sublime Text 2

Tags: c++, g++, sublimetext2

I have the following .sublime-build file to run C++ code on Sublime Text 2:

```
{
"windows":
{
"cmd": ["g++", "$file_name","-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "-lm", "-Wall", "&", "start", "${file_base_name}.exe"]
},
"selector": "source.c++",
"shell": true,
"working_dir": "${file_path}"
}
```

The problem is, I can't pause the screen after building the code. There are plenty of files out there, but that is the only one which worked on my computer. I've tried manually adding "/c", "/k", "& pause" but none of them worked. Any ideas?

Comment: `| more` or `> logfile` ?

Comment: It's just does not work at all, or [Decode error - output not utf-8] appears on console even though I save the file as utf-8 encoding.